# CouchDB View - filter keys before grouping

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a CouchDB database which has documents with the following format:

```
{ createdBy: 'userId', at: 123456, type: 'action_type' }
```

I want to write a view that will give me how many actions of each type were created by which user. I was able to do that creating a view that does this:

```
 emit([doc.createdBy, doc.type, doc.at], 1);
```

With the reduce function "sum" and consuming the view in this way:

/_design/userActionsDoc/_view/userActions?group_level=2

this returns a result with rows just in the way I want:

```
"rows":[ {"key":["userId","ACTION_1"],"value":20}, ...
```

the problem is that now I want to filter the results for a given time period. So I want to have the exact same information but only considering actions which happened within a given time period.

I can filter the documents by "at" if I emit the fields in a different order.

?group_level=3&startkey=[149328316160]&endkey=[1493283161647,{},{}]

```
emit([doc.at, doc.type, doc.createdBy], 1);
```

but then I won't get the results grouped by userId and actionType. Is there a way to have both? Maybe writing my own reduce function?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. I have done two different things in the past to attempt to solve similar issues.

The first pattern is a pain and may work great or may not work at all. I've experienced both. Your map function looks something like this:

```js
function(doc) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[doc.createdBy] = {};
  obj[doc.createdBy][doc.type] = 1;

  emit(doc.at, obj);
  // Ignore this for now
  // emit(doc.at, JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Then your reduce function looks like this:

```js
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  var output = {};
  values.forEach(function(v) {
    // Ignore this for now
    // v = JSON.parse(v);
    for (var user in v) {
      for (var action in v[user]) {
        output[user][action] = (output[user][action] || 0) + v[user][action];
      }
    }
  });
  return output;
  // Ignore this for now
  // return JSON.stringify(output);
}
```

With large datasets, this usually results in a couch error stating that your reduce function is not shrinking fast enough. In that case, you may be able to stringify/parse the objects as shown in the "ignore" comments in the code.

The reasoning behind this is that couchdb ultimately wants you to output a simple object like a string or integer in a reduce function. In my experience, it doesn't seem to matter that the string gets longer, as long as it remains a string. If you output an object, at some point the function errors because you have added too many props to that object.

---

The second pattern is potentially better, but requires that your time periods are "defined" ahead of time. If your time period requirements can be locked down to a specific year, specific month, day, quarter, etc. You just emit multiple times in your map function. Below I assume the `at` property is epoch milliseconds, or at least something that the date constructor can accurately parse.

```js
function(doc) {
  var time_key;
  var my_date = new Date(doc.at);

  //// Used for filtering results in a given year 
  //// e.g. startkey=["2017"]&endkey=["2017",{}]
  time_key = my_date.toISOString().substr(0,4);
  emit([time_key, doc.createdBy, doc.type], 1);

  //// Used for filtering results in a given month
  //// e.g. startkey=["2017-01"]&endkey=["2017-01",{}]
  time_key = my_date.toISOString().substr(0,7);
  emit([time_key, doc.createdBy, doc.type], 1);

  //// Used for filtering results in a given quarter
  //// e.g. startkey=["2017Q1"]&endkey=["2017Q1",{}]
  time_key = my_date.toISOString().substr(0,4) + 'Q' + Math.floor(my_date.getMonth()/3).toString();
  emit([time_key, doc.createdBy, doc.type], 1);
}
```

Then, your reduce function is the same as in your original. Essentially you're just trying to define a constant value for the first item in your key that corresponds to a defined time period.  Works well for business reporting, but not so much for allowing for flexible time periods.